# How to change the color of Collapsible Region lines in Visual Studio 2015/2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017

Need to change the color of this line here:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors -> Display Items -> Outline Margin Vertical Rule -> Item foreground

[image: Screenshot below]

Comment: Thank you that was driving me nuts.

Comment: This setting also changes the *Show Procedure Line Separators* line color.